# Guice injector for library

Tags: guice

I am writing a new java library and want to use guice here. library is going to depend on some other guice modules. I understand that while creating a guice application at some point of time we do Guice.createInjector(...). My question is where should I create the injector in my library as there are many entry points to it.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally the clients of your library would also be using JSR-330 and would just add your modules to their own injectors. If this isn't feasible you could require clients to call an initialization method of your library that would setup your modules, create the injector, and then return some simple factory or provider object (injected by Guice) providing access to the necessary entry points of your API.